# i dont know why the functions aren´t using my variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

i made a variable with a string inside, an then put that variable in two different functions. The problem here is that it shows me an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: mostrarDatosTexto is not defined". I´m not sure enough why is this happening. Here´s the code:

```js
const Libro = (titulo, autor) => {return(

    {
        autor: autor, 
        titulo: titulo,
        mostrarDatosTexto: `${titulo}, de ${autor.toUpperCase()}`,
        mostrarDatosEnConsola:  () => {return (console.log(mostrarDatosTexto))},
        mostrarDatosEnAlert:    () => {return (alert(mostrarDatosTexto))},
    }

)}


let unLibro = Libro('Ángeles y Demonios', 'Dan Brown')

console.log(unLibro)

unLibro.mostrarDatosEnConsola()
unLibro.mostrarDatosEnAlert()
```

i'll really appreciate it if you can help me

Comment: `mostrarDatosTexto` isn't a variable, it's a property of the object. Variables and properties are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mostrarDatosTexto` is a property, not a variable. You need to access it using `XXX.mostrarDatosTexto` syntax.

Inside an object method, you can use `this` to refer to the object that the method was called on. But you have to use an ordinary function, not an arrow function, because arrow functions preserve the value of `this` from the scopre where they were defined, they don't receive it as the method call contact.

`console.log()` and `alert()` don't return anything, so there's no point in using `return` to return their values. Just call them without using `return`.

```js
const Libro = (titulo, autor) => {
  return (
    {
      autor: autor,
      titulo: titulo,
      mostrarDatosTexto: `${titulo}, de ${autor.toUpperCase()}`,
      mostrarDatosEnConsola: function() {
        console.log(this.mostrarDatosTexto);
      },
      mostrarDatosEnAlert: function() {
        alert(this.mostrarDatosTexto);
      },
    }
  )
}


let unLibro = Libro('Ángeles y Demonios', 'Dan Brown')

console.log(unLibro)

unLibro.mostrarDatosEnConsola()
unLibro.mostrarDatosEnAlert()
```